# State definition in Reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

When defining state for a specific problem in reinforcement learning, How to decide what to include and what to leave for the definition, and also how to set difference between an observation and a state.
For example assuming that the agent is in the context of human resource and planning where it needs to hire some workers based on the demand of jobs, considering the cost of hiring them (assuming the budget is limited) is a state in the format of (# workers, cost) a good definition of state?
In total I don't know what information is needed to be in state and what should be left as it's rather observation.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are formulating this as an RL problem because the demand is an unknown quantity. And, maybe [this is optional criteria] the Cost of hiring them may take into account a worker's contribution towards the job which is unknown initially. If however, both these quantities are known or can be approximated beforehand then you can just run a Planning algorithm to solve the problem [or just some sort of Optimization].

Having said this, the state in this problem could be something as simple as (#workers). Note I'm not including the cost, because cost must be experienced by the agent, and therefore is unknown to the agent until it reaches a specific state. Depending on the problem, you might need to add another factor of "time", or the "job-remaining".

Most of the theoretical results on RL hinge on a key assumption in several setups that the environment is [Markovian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property). There are several works where you can get by without this assumption, but if you can formulate your environment in a way that exhibits this property, then you would have much more tools to work with. The key idea being, the agent can decide which action to take (in your case, an action could be : Hire 1 more person. Other actions could be Fire a person) based on the current state, say (#workers = 5, time=6). Note that we are not distinguishing between workers yet, so firing "a" person, instead of firing "a specific" person x. If the workers have differing capabilities, you may need to add several other factors each representing which worker is currently hired, and which are currently in the pool, yet to be hired so like a boolean array of a fixed length. (I hope you get the idea of how to form a state representation, and this can vary based on the specifics of the problem, which are missing in your question).

Now, once we have the State definition S, the action definition A (hire / fire), we have the "known" quantities for an MDP-setup in an RL framework. We also need an environment that can supply us with the cost function when we query it (Reward Function / Cost Function), and tell us the outcome of taking a certain action on a certain state (Transition). Note that we don't necessarily need to know these Reward / Transition function beforehand, but we should have a means of getting these values when we query for a specific (state, action).

Coming to your final part, the difference between observation and state. There are much better resources to dig deep into it, but in a crude sense, observation is an agent's (any agent, AI, human etc) sensory data. For example, in your case the agent has the ability to count number of workers currently employed (but it does not have an ability to distinguish between workers).

A state, more formally, a true MDP state must be something that is Markovian and captures the environment at its fundamental level. So, maybe in order to determine the true cost to the company, the agent needs to be able to differentiate between workers, working hours of each worker, jobs they are working at, interactions between workers and so on. Note that, much of these factors may not be relevant to your task, for example a worker's gender. Typically one would like to form a good hypothesis on which factors are relevant beforehand.

Now, even though we can agree that a worker's assignment (to a specific job) maybe a relevant feature which making a decision to hire or fire them, your observation does not have this information. So you have two options, either you can ignore the fact that this information is important and work with what you have available, or you try to infer these features. If your observation is incomplete for the decision making in your formulation we typically classify them as Partially Observable Environments (and use POMDP frameworks for it).

I hope I clarified a few points, however, there is huge theory behind all of this and the question you asked about "coming up with a state definition" is a matter of research. (Much like feature engineering & feature selection in Machine Learning).

Comment: thank you very much, it is clarified for me now. :)